# Loop Through App.Config file and store each value in variable for C# Console Application?

Tags: c#, console-application

This is structure of my app.config file.

```
<configuration> 
  <IspacDeployConfig>    
    <appSettings> <!-- ISPAC File 1 -->      
      <add key="DestinationProjectFolderPath" value="/SSISDB/Training/Staging" />
      <add key="IspacFilePath" value="C:\ISPAC\Staging.ispac" />
    </appSettings>
    <appSettings> <!-- ISPAC File 2 -->
      <add key="DestinationProjectFolderPath" value="/SSISDB/Training/DataMart" />
      <add key="IspacFilePath" value="C:\ISPAC\DataMart.ispac" />
    </appSettings>    
  </IspacDeployConfig>
</configuration>
```

I want to loop through  and Fetch DestinationProjectFolderPath & IspacFilePath value in variable for further processing. Is there any way to do this without using Custom.config file. So far I used to do following but not sure how do loop through above file.

`ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get`

Loop through xml file and store them in variable for reuse.

```
string DestinationPath = DestinationProjectFolderPath ;                
string ProjectFilePath = IspacFilePath ;
```

Comment: What is the need for storing them to a variable? Is there any specific reason?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below logic to get all the keys from config and add them to a Dictionary. This code will not work if your config has multiple appSettings tags

Note: Please add the required namespace and reference to the project.

```
var appKeys = ((NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.AppSettings).AllKeys;
Dictionary<string, string> allKeys = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (var appKey in appKeys)
{
   if(!allKeys.ContainsKey(appKey))
       allKeys.Add(appKey, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[appKey])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> First create the custom class

```
 public class CustomConfig
    {
        private static List< Dictionary<string, string>> keyValuePairs = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

        public CustomConfig()
        {
            var xml = XDocument.Load(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location + ".config");


            var query = from c in xml.Root.Descendants("appSettings")
                        select c;

            foreach (var apps in query)
            {
                var addkeys = apps.Descendants("add");
                Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                foreach (var item in addkeys)
                {
                    dic.Add(item.FirstAttribute.Value, item.LastAttribute.Value);

                }
                keyValuePairs.Add(dic);
            }
        }
      
        public Dictionary<string, string> this [int index]
        {
            get
            {
               return keyValuePairs[index];
            }
        }

    }
```

> Then in the Main method access members using below code:

```
string DestinationProjectFolderPath1 = new CustomConfig()[0]["DestinationProjectFolderPath"];
            string DestinationProjectFolderPath2 = new CustomConfig()[1]["DestinationProjectFolderPath"];

            string IspacFilePath1 = new CustomConfig()[0]["IspacFilePath"];
            string IspacFilePath2 = new CustomConfig()[1]["IspacFilePath"];
```